# Use refresh_token to obtain new id_token with Auth0 Lock 10 / Auth0.js 8?

Tags: javascript, auth0

I need to use a refresh_token (which I have stored) to obtain a new id_token from Auth0.

In version 9 of Auth0 Lock, there was a method to do this ([as documented here](https://auth0.com/docs/libraries/lock/v9/using-a-refresh-token)):

```
lock.getClient().refreshToken(refresh_token, function (err, delegationResult) {
  // Get here the new JWT via delegationResult.id_token
});
```

In Lock 10, `getClient()` no longer exists, and [this page](https://auth0.com/docs/libraries/lock/v10/auth0js) suggests that you can instantiate your own instance of `auth0.js`. How do I do this?

I tried this:

```
return new auth0.WebAuth({
    domain: '...',
    clientID: '...'
});
```

but this object doesn't seem to have any useful methods on it. Again the old [Auth0.js v7](https://auth0.com/docs/libraries/auth0js/v7) library looks clear:

```
auth0.refreshToken(refresh_token, function (err, delegationResult) {
  // Get here the new delegationResult.id_token
});
```

How can this be achieved with auth0.js v8?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [available documentation](https://auth0.com/docs/libraries/auth0js#using-renewauth-to-acquire-new-tokens) the way to obtain a new token using Auth0.js v8 is to use the `renewAuth` method.

> The `renewAuth` method allows you to acquire a new token from Auth0 for a user who is already authenticated against the hosted login page.

Comment: So this is not possible with an embedded lock widget?

Answer (score 3):

As pointed out, `renewAuth` seems to be the new way to do this. However, it's also possible to make a manual HTTP call to the Auth0 api in order to get a new id token using a refresh token:

```
POST {yourAuth0Domain}/delegation

{
    client_id: "...",
    grant_type: "urn:ietf:params:oauth:grant-type:jwt-bearer",
    refresh_token: "...",
    scope: "openid app_metadata"
}
```